# If $X,Y$ are the Haudorff Space, can one deduce that , if $f$ is continous open mapping ,then $f$ is an injective?

Tags: general-topology

If $X,Y$ are the Haudorff Space, can one deduce that , if $f$ is a continous open mapping ,then $f$ is an injective?

Well, I think the condition Haudorff Space is necessary, for there is an example :

$$f:X\mapsto Y$$
Where $X,Y$ both have the trival topology, and $f$ is a surjective , obviously it is continous and an open mapping , but it is not injective.

Comment: This is false, isn't it?

Comment: Are you assuming surjectivity? Because the map $\frac{x}{1 + |x|}$ leaps to mind.

Comment: @Randall Yes. Take $f : X \rightarrow X$, with $X$ given the discrete topology, as a constant map.

Comment: Consider the continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto e^{x}$. It seems like this map is open, but it is not a homeomorphism (because it is not surjective).

Comment: @AlexanderLau still no.

Comment: @Randall Yes I see, so it seems like that the injective holds only in a metric space , and I know how to deal with this , thanks all of you ~

Comment: The projection $p_1(r_1,r_2)=r_1$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous and open but not injective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $X$ to be $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual topology and $Y=\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology and $f(x,y)=x$, the projection. Then $f$ is open, continuous and very non-injective, but onto. Both spaces are metric so certainly Hausdorff.

Projections are among the canonical examples of open and continuous maps. Many examples of this form exist.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a space with $\lvert X \rvert > 1$ given the discrete topology. Singletons are open, so $X$ is Hausdorff. Let $x_0 \in X$.

Define $f : X \rightarrow X$ by $f(x) = x_0$ for $x \in X$.

$f$ is continuous and open, but neither injective nor surjective.